# Creating 'document' environment using AUCTeX leaves a blank line after \end{document}

Tags: emacs, auctex

If I type `C-c C-e document` in AUCTeX mode using Eamcs, I end up with a blank line after `\end{document}`; see

[image: output]

Can I stop AUCTeX from producing this extra line at the end?

Notes: I use Emacs 24.3-13 with AUCTeX 11.87-7 on a Fedora system.

Comment: It's pretty common to have files ending with a newline (for instance, GCC used to expect a newline at the end of C source file), why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @giordano Because I almost never write comments after `\end{document}` and it saves a line of code every time.

Comment: It's common (and useful) to set local Emacs variables at the end of the file and a blank line separating `%%% Local variables:` from `\end{document}` is good. Saving a byte doesn't seem so important.

Comment: @egreg Okay. Then I guess I'll just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defadvice LaTeX-env-document
  (around LaTeX-env-document-delete-newline activate)
  "Delete newline after \\end{document}."
  ad-do-it
  (save-excursion
    (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
    (delete-char 1)))
```

Comment: Are you sure? Nothing seems to change for me when I add these lines. (I'll investigate later today, when time allows me to.)

Comment: Leave the point after the code and evaluate it with `C-x C-e`.  You need to manually evaluate it only if you don't restart Emacs.

Comment: Did you try `C-h v require-final-newline RET`?